# Unable to get music notation with abc package

Tags: shell-escape, music

I want to do some simple music notation and decided to try the `abc` package as a less-steep option. However when I tried the simple example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{abc}
\begin{document}
Text
\begin{abc}[name=c-dur]
X: 1 % start of header
K: C % scale: C major
"Text"C4 G4 | (3FED c4 G2 |
\end{abc}
\end{document}
```

running as

```
"%texpath%bin\win32\pdflatex.exe" --shell-escape mwe.tex
```

or

```
"%texpath%bin\win32\pdflatex.exe" -shell-escape mwe.tex
```

then it compiles but with the (clearly not correct) error:

```
Package abc Warning: You have set the `shellescape' option, but you ran
(abc)                (pdf)latex without the `-shell-escape' command line
(abc)                option. Fix it either with the `noshellescape' option
(abc)                in your document or the correct call of (pdf)latex.
```

Compilation completes but with partial output as below. On Windows 8.1. My Texlive installation did not initially include music, but I later added the abc package only (so may be other dependencies missing but not reported?). What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: It seems to be a Windows issue. Can you please try adding `\the\pdfshellescape` after `Text` and see what number is printed?

Comment: Text 1. I do use -shell-escape regularly for other purposes (concatenating files using command line, splitindex etc).

Comment: Very strange; can you tell what version of `abc.sty` you have?

Comment: Only just downloaded from Texlive. Top of file says 2015/09/09 v2.0a. Texlive package manager says 38340 (2.0a)

Comment: Oh, I forgot! Did you install `abcm2ps` on your machine? See http://abcplus.sourceforge.net/#abcm2ps

Comment: Yup. Not installed as such but considering this I stuck abcm2ps.exe and all the various other files that came in the zip on sourceforge into the same folder as mwe.tex where I presume it will be found. Same warning same output.

Comment: `abcm2ps.exe` must be installed among the binaries. Sorry, but as a Windows-free user, I don't know how to help.

Comment: Windows normally sees binaries in project folder, but I installed in bin folder (where pdflatex itself is located). No help. I also installed epstopdf epstopdfconversion packages in case. The full log is here https://www.dropbox.com/s/bhbnn2fzoa0xcid/mwe.log?dl=0

Comment: I think you should ask for help to Guido Gonzato (mail address at the bottom of the ABCplus project page).

Comment: I'm in a very similar boat: "You can create music sheets within the abc-environment:" followed by a box that reads "c-dur".

Comment: I have also downloaded `abcm2ps`. It has a file called `INSTALL` that says `Change the file 'config.h' according to your preferences, compile all
the '.c' files using an ANSI C compiler, and link them together.` My C is very rusty, but hey, maybe I can make sense of a `config.h` file. Except I don't see `config.h`, I see `chinese.abc` and then `deco.abc`. There's also some DLLs in there.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP's system doesn't have abcm2ps installed (and how to install it is outside this site's scope)

Comment: Not sure I agree totally. Firstly the error message is misleading. Second given the number of up-votes, many others simply cannot get this to work or install in windows via any mechanism. Knowing that others cannot get a particular package to work (at all) is helpful to know and time-saving. Sometimes an answer to a question (at least at a particular point in time) *is* that there is no answer. I would certainly have liked to have seen this question (and absence of answer) before embarking on a time-consuming quest related to a tangential error message.

Comment: To add: It is not the case of not having abcm2ps installed - it is a case of having it installed and working, and additionally placed in a variety of other places LaTex would likely look - and still having the examples not compile while claiming (falsely) that -shellescape is off.